# Pyspark + Redis Remote Server

Tags: redis, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, redis-server

I have a server with redis and maven configured 
I then do the following sparkSession

```
spark = pyspark
.sql
.SparkSession
.builder
.master('local[4]')
.appName('try_one_core')
.config("spark.redis.host", "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX")
.config("spark.redis.port", "6379")
.config("spark.redis.auth", "XXXX")
.getOrCreate()
```

I am trying to connect to a remote redis server and write/load data from it, however when I try to .save() with the following command

```
df
.write
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis")
.option("table", "df")
.option("key.column", "case_id")
.save()
```

I get the following error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   o327.save. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data
>   source: org.apache.spark.sql.redis. Please find packages at
>   http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Is there any fix to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As addition to @fe2s answer , instead of loading it from disk or network storage it can be also loaded directly from maven

```
bin/pyspark --packages com.redislabs:spark-redis:2.4.0
```

the `--packages` and `--jars`  arguments can also be used with normal `spark-submit` command

Answer (score 2):

It means that `spark-redis-<version>-jar-with-dependencies.jar` is not loaded in Spark.

You have to run pyspark with the following arguments as stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/blob/master/doc/python.md):

`$ bin/pyspark --jars <path-to>/spark-redis-<version>-jar-with-dependencies.jar --conf "spark.redis.host=localhost" --conf "spark.redis.port=6379" --conf "spark.redis.auth=passwd"`

Comment: I have this server configured with redis to be accessed remotely, then on my computer I am establishing a connection through pySpark code with a the specified spark session, however should I have maven also installed on my computer? or only on the remote server that is being accessed